# js match - get file extension in path

Tags: javascript, regex, match, point

How to get file extension in path using JavaScript?

```
alert("http://max/fi.le.rar".match(/\..*/i));
```

returns data since first dot

```
.le.rar
```

but I need only .rar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
"http://max/fi.le.rar".match(/\.[^.]+$/);
```

Comment: I should comment that the returning value is an array of string

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = "http://max/fi.le.rar";
var extention = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."), path.length);
```

I did a test with substring and split from @wisdom.
After 500000 times:

.rar Execution time: 47ms  (sub)
 rar Execution time: 53ms (split without dot)
(after some more testing the execution times are about the same)

---

I have no experience with match

Answer (score 0):

or You can use javascript `split()` function like this

```
var str="http://max/fi.le.rar";
var n=str.split(".");
alert(n[n.length - 1]);
```